# Serving HTTPS with Cloudfront but backing HTTP orgin

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a Wordpress server running on EC2 and currently it's only running HTTP and I'd rather avoid the hassle of setting up SSL on it. What I'm hoping is that I can co-opt Cloudfront to serve all requests to clients using HTTPS (using an AWS Certificate Managed SSL cert) and then refresh it's cache with HTTP calls to the origin server. This type of configuration is quite straight forward with Cloudflare but it's more of a reverse-proxy than a traditional CDN. Is this a reasonable architecture for Cloudfront?

I had originally thought that the "Behavior" for Viewer Protocol Policy could be set to "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" but at least initially I appear to be getting the page to load over HTTPS but all assets on the page fail to load because they're still pointed to HTTP. Possibly this a different issue but I'm having an issue grokking it all.

Just for reference, here's my Behaviors dashboard:

[image]

And my origin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `Origin Protocol Policy` option in AWS Console. Select `HTTP Only`.

To do this select your Cloudfront configuration > choose `Origins and Origin Groups` tab > Choose your origin > Click `Edit` button

[image]

Remember that you are doing changes for `Origin`. You have to keep `Viewer Protocol Policy` to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` as indicated in the question so that traffic between browser and Cloudfront remains `HTTPS` whereas Cloudfront connects to your `Origin` via `HTTP`

Edit: Question description does show that origin is set to HTTP Only which should be enough to do it. Double check if your distribution is in `Deployed` state.

Comment: This does not help, all css/images  and js are failing, browser is trying to load them with http and cloudfront is denying it. blocked:mixed-content

Answer (score -1):

After setting up CloudFront to deal with HTTPS, you also need to configure WordPress so it generates all the links and asset sources with HTTPS. You can follow the [documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/) for that.

In short:

1. Go to Settings -> General
2. Change `http://` to `https://` in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).

[image]

Comment: I am afraid this does not answer the question which is how to serve clients using 
 `HTTPS` while having `HTTP` EC2 backend using Cloudfront.

Comment: It is part of the question: "...at least initially I appear to be getting the page to load over HTTPS but all assets on the page fail to load because they're still pointed to HTTP"